# AngularJS Need to bind parent checkbox with child without using ng-model

Tags: angularjs, checkbox, parent-child, angular-ngmodel, angularjs-ng-checked

I got an User list using `ng-repeat` via an `API` call.
For every User their is 5 categories and each category got 2-3 authorizations on `true/false`.

For every `user/category/authorization` I want a checkbox that will change the value of authorization.

When I check the checkbox of a User I want all his 5 categories + all the authorizations been check `true` and if I uncheck one authorization or categories of a User his checkbox will go `false`.

So if I recapitulate: there is a `parent(User)`, `child(Category)` and grand `child(Authorization)`.

I saw that we can use `ng-model` with `ng-checked` but in my checkbox, the `ng-model` is used for the `boolean authorization (ng-model="authorization.Enabled")` and for more than 1 child this no more work.

How can I manage this case ? Need a `$watcher` ?

Thanks for your help !

Comment: Please illustrate your question with a code sample.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/pio123/624y6/1/

I need this thing but without using `ng-model` because my `ng-model` is already used for my authorization.Enabled

Answer (score 0):

You can use ng-click on each child/grand child. 
Pass parent object (user or cathegory) object in it and modify its boolean value on specific condition (when all childs are true or not)
You shouldn't use ng-click and ng-model together, you can avoid doing this by use ng-checked and ng-click on parent(user or cathegory) checkbox.

```
vm.authorizationCheckboxClick = function (user,category, authorization) {
authorization.booleanValue = !authorization.booleanValue;
if (authorization.booleanValue){
    category.booleanValue = true;
    category.authorizations.forEach(function(element) {
      if(!element.booleanValue){
        category.booleanValue = false;
        break;
      }
    }, this);
}
else {
  category.booleanValue = false;
}

if (category.booleanValue){
    user.booleanValue = true;
    user.categories.forEach(function(element) {
      if(!element.booleanValue){
        user.booleanValue = false;
        break;
      }
    }, this);
}
else {
  user.booleanValue = false;
}
}
```

This example function changing value of authorizations and then changing bolean values of parent category and user. You can bind this values to ng-checked directive